# "Extend" a BigQuery array using rows in a different table

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I have two BigQuery tables, the first is called `model_results` containing two columns `model_name` (string) and `vars` (repeated record with elements `id` and `value`), and the second table is called `model_details` containing two columns `model_name` (string) and `vars_details` (repeated record with elements `id` and `description`). For example:

[image: Source tables]

Essentially what I want to do is to take `model_results` and "extend" it using the information in `model_details`. That is, for each row in `model_results` with a certain `model_name`, I want to look up the row in `model_details` with that same `model_name` and "append" `vars_details` to that row from `model_results`. In the example above, the output would be:

[image: Output table]

My knowledge of BigQuery arrays, structs, and `UNNEST`'s is not that great, which is why I haven't been able to succeed so far. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
select model_name,
  array(
    select as struct t.*, description
    from t1.vars t
    join t2.vars_details
    using(id)
  ) vars
from `project.dataset.model_results` t1
join `project.dataset.model_details` t2
using(model_name)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]